# Laradock - Remove port from the url not working

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I´ve been searching a lot and found a lot of answers but unfortunately non of the answers is working, my scenario is below:

In my project folder i have laradock and laravel folders. In the .env(inside laradock) i have:

```
NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT=8080
```

and this is because my 80 is ocuppied. and inside the nginx folder, in the default.conf i have:(note that the code below is pratically the default, i have putted here many things but it didn´t work)

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # For https
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    server_name mam1.test;
    root /var/www/laravelProject/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile i have to edit the hosts file on my mac and put: 127.0.0.1 laravelProject. If i acess laravelProject on my url it shows a message saying, **it works** which is not what i want, bu if i access with laravelProject:8080 it works great!. **but how do i remove the port?** i have tried many things, the last one was [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/access-my-web-site-without-the-port-in-the-url) but if it keeps NOT redirecting to the correct url.

How do i do this?
Regards

Comment: You need to use port '80' for Nginx so that it can send the requests to service. If your NGINX is running on '8080', you need to send a request on `8080`, btw just curious, what are you running on port `80`, because usually, you run webservers like Nginx on 80

Comment: Hi, thanks for anserwing...if i go to my network utility to see what ports are between 80 and 90, it says that port 80 is occupied by http...but i dont understand what you are saying, in the end what should be my configuration? wich files should i alter?..and i cant 'up' my containers if i use NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT=80...because it gives me an error saying the port is already in use

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? And can you check which process is using port 80?

Comment: I´m on a mac, but i think i know what is the problem, i cannot have two instances of webservers using the same port, so i went the network utility and the port 80 is being occupied by httpd....what is this?